# Why typescript (webpack) does not show where the error is coming from during import?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I receive an error during webpack compilation:

```
ERROR in d:\Work\.Projects\projectweb\VueApp\app.ts
./VueApp/app.ts
[tsl] ERROR in d:\Work\.Projects\projectweb\VueApp\app.ts(2,32)
      TS2551: Property 'setPrototypeOf' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Did you mean 'getPrototypeOf'?
```

(and more)

My `app.ts` is very simple:

```
import { Component, Emit, Inject, Model, Prop, Provide, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import VueBase from './vueBase';

@Component({})
export default class App extends VueBase {

}
```

There is no `setPrototypeOf` and the problem is obviously coming from the import. Why doesn't the error show proper location, but instead shows me that an error is in `app.ts`?

`tsconfig`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

webpack config:

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
  target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

  entry: './VueApp/main.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
          ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
            'vue-style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
            loaders: {
                // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                'scss': [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
                'sass': [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
            // other vue-loader options go here
        }
    },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
      alwaysNotify: true
  }),
  ]
};
module.exports = config;
```

I also would like to know why the error comes up in the first place.

I've tried typescript versions `3.6.3` and `2.9.2`

Comment: try this: set "target": "es2016",
        "module": "es6",

Comment: normally it should worked with es2015